# How to find and replace a string using a batch file or vbs

Tags: xml, batch-file, replace, vbscript, find

I need some help. I have a tmp file that the name changes. The content stays the same but the GPO changes the name on each computer and each time the GPO applies. The file is in a directory by itself and it sets a wireless profile in Win7.

I need a way to search for the file. The name is always different but its the only file in the directory (i.e C:\Windows\wlansvc\Policies) and than search and replace the sting with the below value.
The string that need to changed is: auto 
replace with manual

Any help would be great... Thanks.

Comment: for the "search and replace" part see the "Related" questions at the right side of this page. This question has been answered dozends and dozends of times.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%i in ("C:\Windows\wlansvc\Policies\*") do echo %%~fi
```